# Test for gaussian mixture fit when component assignment is known?

Tags: normality-assumption, gaussian-mixture-distribution, false-discovery-rate, shapiro-wilk-test

I have a process  generating random variables `X_1, ... X_n`. From each of these I've sampled a set of samples `S_i = (s_i1, ... s_im)`, respectively.

I want to test whether the process/real-world dynamic generating the variables `X_i` is consistently (or pretty consistently) generating normally distributed variables (not identically distributed, though! They can have different μ and σ).

One suggestion I got was to think of all samples `(S_1, ..., S_n)` as coming from a gaussian mixture. However, it didn't come with a suggestion for a statistical test, and I couldn't find one.

My original thought was to test each sample separately for normality (with something like Shapiro-Wilks), control the False Discovery Rate in the set of tests (using something like Benjamini-Yekutieli; I can't assume independence), and then see whether the rate of rejections (in the case of Shapiro-Wilks, this means non-normality) is under/over some predetermined threshold (like 10% or 20%), in which case I deem the mysterious process as one not generating gaussians consistently enough.

However, I'm no statistician, so I've come to ask for help.
Thank you! :)

*Clarification:*

One shouldn't think of `X_i` as if they were collected from the same process.   is a process generating processes, if you want. Or distributions, or populations.

Think of  as "my marketing team" and different X as different marketing campaings they output, where each such campaign generates different revenue streams, or engagement streams. One might be a tv campaign in Belfast, another an online campaign in Kenya. We thus do not expect the revenue/engaement/whatever distribution for all of them to have the same μ and σ. Therefore, the question is whether revenue streams from campaigns generally distribute normally or not.

Comment: It's not clear to me why, given that you've collected variables from a particular process and sampled from them apparently at random, you think the underlying distributions might be different.  How did you generate your samples?  Why would the underlying distributions for the samples be different, given that the population was generated by the (one) process $P$?

Comment: They were not collected from the same process. P is a process generating processes, if you want. Or distributions, or populations. 

Think of  as "my marketing team" and different X as different marketing campaings they output, where each such campaign generates different revenue streams, or engagement streams.  One might be a tv campaign in Belfast, another an online campaign in Kenya. Do you really expect the revenue/engaement/whatever distribution for all of them to have the same μ and σ? Thus, the questions is whether revenue streams from campaigns generally distribute normally or not.

Comment: Ah, that helps.  You might want to rewrite your first couple of sentences to reflect that.

Comment: Right you are! Done and done! :)

Comment: How many random variables do you have, and how formal a solution do you need? You can of course inspect and separately test all individual samples, from which you can learn more than by just running a single overall test. Every adjustment for multiple testing has pros and cons, but how much do you need to bother? Formal tests are for specific decision problems, and I'm not sure if this is what you need.

Comment: By the way, I find your "original thought" pretty sensible, and I doubt that testing for a mixture can improve on that (as this may muddle information together that should not be muddled).